# Guice servlet 405 err: seems to not set Content-type set to "text/json" for MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

Tags: jqgrid, guice, jackson, guice-servlet

I'm making a call from jQGrid to a Guice servlet that has the following binding:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/{param}")
public String getJson(@PathParam("param") String param) {
    ...
    return return json.toString();
}
```

Requesting the url directly, I can see the JSON.  When jqgrid executes the request, I get 405 method not allowed response.  I've seen this happen before when the returning page doesn't have the Content-type set to "text/json" (jqgrid is not very flexible here).

HERE IS THE REQUEST:
Key Value
Request POST /myapp/json/jqgrid/json ... HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with    XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language en-us
Referer http://localhost:8080/myapp/myPage...
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host    localhost:8080
Content-Length  63
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache

HERE IS THE RESPONSE:
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow   GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length  1034

Any thoughts on how to get the guice servlet to set the Content-type to "text/json" and allow the response?

Comment: "text/json" is wrong `Content-type` for the JSON response. Correct `Content-type` is "application/json". See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type/477819#477819)

Comment: The request was actually "Accept application/json" (see my REQUEST output above).  The problem is the response from the Guice servlet is coming back as Content-Type text/html;charset=utf-8.  In Guice I've tried several @Produces combinations to get the application/json with no luck although MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON should generate the correct response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is solved.  I was using a @GET annotation and jQGrid was issuing a post.  I changed the @POST and it started working.  This may solve the problem for others with related 405 errors.